# How can I trace where my connection is stalling?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

My network setup is:

> 1 WAN
>
> 1 pfsense router
>
> 1 wireless AP running tomato
>
> About 9 wireless devices
>
> 1 wired connection from my AP to my desktop.

Well starting yesterday, I started having internet problems. What happens is it takes a long time for an internet connection to fully initialize.

Example:

On my cellphone(Galaxy S5), I tried to watch youtube videos. Well when I open a youtube video, it takes a moment for my wifi to establish a connection from youtube to my phone. The video doesnt take long to load. That part is instant. It just takes long for the video to actually be initialized.

I also ran a speedtest from my cell phone. It took a long moment for the speed test to begin(initialize a connection) but when it actually ran the speed test, I got 11 ms ping 60 download 10 upload.

One more example: I opened the google playstore on my phone. It took a moment for all of the app images to pop up when normally they all load almost instantly. I also tried installing an app. It took a long moment for the app download to start, but when it did start, the app downloaded instantly.

This is where I'm confused. My internet speeds are perfectly fine. Theres just something that is causing it to delay a connection between my devices. so instead of youtube being loaded in instantly, I have to wait for one of my devices to fully communicate with my router and/or AP.

How can I find the issue?

I have tested it on multiple devices btw. My tablet, my phone and my desktop. They all do the same thing.

So that isolates it to either my AP or my router, right? Well now Im not sure considering that my tablet will randomly turn off its wifi. It doesnt drop the wifi connection. The wifi service just turns off completely. My tablet has never done that before but now its doing it frequently all of a sudden as a result of these issues im having. Well my AP wouldnt be a reason for my tablet to shut off its wifi service and force me to manually turn it on again, right? Everything is messing up and idk why. Its all over the place.

Well, I did a factory reset on both my router and my AP. The problem still persists. I erased the nvram on my router, but when I did a factory reset of the pfsense machine I noticed that during the initial setup process, it had all of my choices and settings still saved. Meaning theres some kind of cache saving all that data. I tried to find it on google and when I searched pfsense cache, the only thing that comes up is squid cache which doesnt apply to me.

I tried to ping my AP and my router from my desktop. When I ping the router, it happens instantly.

```
Ping statistics for 10.12.1.1:    
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),    
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:    
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When I ping the AP it happens **nearly** instantly as well.

```
Ping statistics for 10.12.1.201:    
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),    
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:    
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 9ms, Average = 2ms
```

Im guessing its the AP from those results. Well when I do tracert to my AP, it takes about 6 seconds for tracert to initialize then and display my results. Just like how it takes 6 seconds for any kind of internet application to initialize on my devices.

Heres the results though.

```
Tracing route to 10.12.1.201 over a maximum of 30 hops
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms
```

However, when I do tracert to my router, the results pop up instantly. It doesnt have that 6 second delay.

```
Tracing route to BPC [10.12.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  BPC [10.12.1.1]
```

Which makes me think even more that the issue is my AP. But that still doesnt explain why my tablet shuts off its wifi service. I'll assume the AP is the issue though.

What do I do? This AP is only 2 months old. Before I installed pfsense, this AP was my wireless router. It never gave me any issues. Even after I turned it into an AP only, it still worked fine with pfsense. I only started to get this issue late last night and today.

I didnt change any settings on the AP last night or any time recently. And even so I still wiped all the settings on both. The only thing I changed on my router last night was a blacklist for a massive list of ad servers. But I erased all of them and the problem still persists. I also cleared the arp table on my router.

`arp -a -d` That is all I did regarding the devices.

I also tried doing traceroute and ping on my phone.

When I ping my router, the results are

```
min: 6.5ms
max: 32.63ms
avg: 18.73ms
```

When I ping my AP. the results are

```
min: 22.5ms
max: 35.66ms
avg: 28.51ms
```

When I traceroute the router, it runs through all 30 hops and then it doesnt display any results. It just says

```
1 * * * 

2 * * *
```

And it goes all the way up to 30 and then its done.

When I traceroute the AP, it does 1 hop and the results pop up immediately.

```
10.12.1.201 (10.12.1.201) 23.475ms 17.028ms 4.507ms
```

So what I've found out is that when I run those commands using a wired connection, the AP seems to be where it stalls. When I run the commands from my phone, it still takes longer to ping my AP, but instead of traceroute happening faster when I do it to my router, it happens faster when I do it to my AP; and it doesnt even seem to complete when I do it to my router.

Anything else I can do?

Is it my AP or router? This isn't normal behavior and I would like to fix it.

I googled it and one page said it might be the DNS. Well I changed the DNS on pfsense from my ISP's servers to 8.8.8.8 and opendns.

Comment: The long time to start initially sounds like a DNS problem. Is the problem still present when you use a specific IP address rather than a DNS name? If not, try using different DNS server(s).

Comment: What do you mean? Like try to get onto youtube with its ip instead of youtube.com? 

I tried it using the IP and I cant notice much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you trace the Router its FAST because the router responds to DNS for itself quickly.

When you trace the AP its SLOW because the AP isnt responding/announcing a DNS name so it must wait for it to timeout.

If you use

```
tracert -d [Target]
```

Both will be quick.

Check that your clients arent DHCPing off the AP instead of the router and thus getting incorrect DNS addresses. If thats all ok, then you need to see whats going on with DNS in the PFSense box.